# PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException

Tags: postsharp

When compiling my project, which is having a Postsharp aspect (OnMethodBoundaryAspect) getting the error as

*"Unhandled exception (4.0.41.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Cannot get the reflection object".*

But this error message appears only on few machines, and the same project file is compiling successfully on most of the other machines.

I am using Visual studio 2013 and .net framework 4.5. 
Postsharp dll version is 4.0.41

Please suggest the possible reason for this or any fix for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="PostSharp"
                      publicKeyToken="b13fd38b8f9c99d7"
                      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.39.0"
                     newVersion="4.0.39.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

app.config is the first place I would look for errors of this nature. Make sure the references are correct.

Unfortunately though, I still get this error i some cases that I can't discover why yet.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using 4.3.43.0 fixed it by replacing 
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0-4.3.26.0" newVersion="4.3.26.0" />
to
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.3.43.0" newVersion="4.3.43.0" />